# Its ABP Framework project and its .NET project with microservices. Its been in dockerised state and i want to deploy it on EKS

Tags: microservices

How to deploy .net project in EKS and the framework is ABP suite.

Tries helm but its giving "HTTPapi.HOST TERMITED unexpectedly" error .

I am new to Kubernetes but I have running docker-compose which basically deploys the Catalog API and Catalog DB.

While working with docker-compose:

I have used docker-compose.override.yaml to override the connection string from local to another container we have for the database like.
Is that a correct approach?
What is the server name should I specify in Kubernetes secret?